# Getting unexplainable error "Requiring unknown module '4'"

Tags: react-native, expo

I don't even know where to begin because i'm not requiring no such module.

I've tried to save every file in my project.
I've tried to reload my apps on expo

Im using a Samsung A10 E android phone to run this app with expo go

Answer (score 6):

completely restart expo on both devices